# How to use an IF statement in node.twig

Tags: theming, 8

In node.twig (output for articles) I want to use the value of boolean content type field like this, but do not know how to realize this in drupal 8.

```
if boolean content type is true {
  <div class="text">
   {{ content.body }}
  </div>
else {
  <div class="img">
   {{ content.img }}
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Is your question - "I want to display a different field depending on if the node has a particular field or is of a particular content type so that I can add the text or img class selector to the div element"?

Comment: my question is I want do display different content type fields in dependence whether boolean content type is true or false

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According the [Twig If documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/if.html), you would do it like this:

```
{% if content.field_boolean == true %}
  <div class="text">
   {{ content.body }}
  </div>
{% else %}
  <div class="img">
   {{ content.field_image }}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

You need to use `content.[machine name]` **you can find the machine name of you fields in Manage Display of your content type.**

From my example. change `content.field_boolean` to the machine name of your boolean field. If your boolean field is called "cool" then replace it with `content.field_cool`

Remember to clear/flush the cache to see changes.

Comment: Hej, it's me again. I tried but this does not work :( 
even the following little snippet does not work
`{% if content.boolean == true %}
<h2>this is boolean true</h2>
{% endif %}`
Do you have another idea??

Comment: @lesleyn. edited my answer, hopefully it's clear now `:)`

Comment: if your Boolean field is called cool then your snipped is `{% if content.field_cool == true %} <h2>this is boolean true</h2> {% endif %}` if this still does not work try using 1 instead of true `{% if content.field_cool == 1 %} <h2>this is boolean true</h2> {% endif %}`

Comment: I got it! But I can see it only in the sub-page not at start-page in teaser. I use in the end this snippet  `{% if content.field_cool == true %} <div>   <p> Boolean is true! </p> </div>  {% else %} <div><p> Boolean is false!  </p> </div> {% endif %}` And in teaser at start-page I only got the answer "BOOLEAN IS FALSE!". Do you know what I have to do to see it in teaser at start-page, too???

Comment: @lesleyn. I feel like you should ask this as a separate question since the front page uses Views to generate the teasers.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `.value` to check if a boolean field has value in the twig template. What I did was this and it worked:

```
{% if content.field_some_boolean_field.value %}
  <div class="text">
    {{ content.body }}
  </div>
{% else %}
  <div class="img">
    {{ content.img }}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried solutions given above. But not worked for me. Below code worked for me.

```
{% if node.field_some_boolean_field.0.value == '1' %}
  <div class="text">
    {{ content.body }}
  </div>
{% else %}
  <div class="img">
    {{ content.img }}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```